# simple return in java class

Tags: java, class, servlets, return

Instead of writing too many sql statements in each servlet I just want to write one sql statement in a java class and want to call that class from each servlet but I have not found the correct way to do so.

The sql statement is: `select distinct username from table where userid=?`

```
while (rs.next){
    username=rs.getString(1);
}
```

I want to return `username` to each servlet
so I created a java class in netbeans:

```
public class Username {
     //How should I proceed here?        
}
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  What do you want this class to do?  What have you got so far?

Comment: simply i want to return `username(in rs.next())` from that `class` in each jsp/servlet and this class has nothing to do with servlets/jsps, simply i want to display `username` in a jsp. so i have 5 jsp pages, each time in stead of writing sql statements 5 times i want to display `username(in rs.next())` by returning this `username` from `java class`

Comment: any idea Mike please give any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't embed that code in a servlet.

Create a separate POJO that does the work for you.  Write it, test it, and give a reference to any servlet that needs its services.  Let the servlet call the one method that executes that logic.

Start with an interface:

```
package persistence;

public inteface UserDao {
    String getUsername(Long userId);
}
```

Then give it an implementation:

```
package persistence; 

public class UserDaoimpl implements UserDao {
    public String getUsername(Long userId) {
        // All the SQL stuff here
    }
}
```

Your servlet will have a reference to it:

```
private UserDao userDao = new UserDaoImpl();
```

The servlet should acquire the Connection from a pool and give it to the DAO.

If you have write operations, I'd recommend that you create a separate service layer.  Services know about units of work.  They'll outlive your web UI and those servlets.

Comment: thanks a lot duffymo for your answer just a doubt, where should i put return statement in that class?

Comment: yes one more doubt is i am getting `userid` from `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);` but error is coming for that `request` in that class. any suggestion please

Comment: What you're trying to do is look at the username the client is passing and seeing if it exists in the database.  I've sorted out the database side.  The fact that there's a problem with the request is a separate issue.  Please clarify your question, or ask another one.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got your question.
I hope you get the answer in following code:-

```
public class Username {

    public String getUserName(Long userId) {
        String userName = "";
        //all your sql code here
        return userName;
    }
}
```

write the following code in the servlet class

```
Username uName = new Username();
uName.getUserName(userId);
```

Comment: yes bhavesh good way but in servlet how should i call this `userName`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling each time class form each servlet to get username, why  you do not using `ServletContext`

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("username", username);
```

or different ways put, POJO class into session attribute or in context attribute